# Testing for infinite loops

Tags: autotools

I'm horsing around with an esoteric programming language, small s.c.r.i.p.t.

At the same time trying to come to grips with GNU Autotools, and autotest.

Just curious if there are preferred methods of testing around infinite loops.  Meaning, I'd like to test for infinite loops as expected behaviour from certain constructs.

Is there a paradigm, or is this just; too bad, don't bother, write different tests?

Edit:
Adding a corollary;  Is there anything in Autotest for performance testing?  I know the edge cases can't really be nailed down from run to run, but a 'test took longer than 1 second' warning level would be a nice feature.  I've been looking, and don't see anything in the framework, but did find samples of tests (I had to build a CARL9170 device driver and the sources have some examples), but those are explicit tests, and not really the framework warning if things are taking too long.